# GCloud compute engine - Permissions issue for the owner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have been facing a very weird issue for the last 2 weeks and haven't managed to solve it.

As the owner of the project I get "You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page" when I am trying to access the monitoring tab under VM instance details.

I am the owner of several other projects and the functionality is there but for my initial project I get this message.

Any clue why this happens?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE : Started getting a new message now "Sorry, there’s a problem. If you entered information, check it and try again. Otherwise, the problem might clear up on its own, so check back later."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is fixed after Gcloud Support investigation. There is a small bug on escaping a keyword of the project name with this causing the error that I was facing.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

There could be various reasons for this:

1- the API for Stackdriver monitoring is not enabled on your project. If your project was created quite some time ago, you must check that the Stackdriver monitoring API is enabled, for more recent project , you don’t need to enable it to see the monitoring charts of the instances.
  Check if it enabled from this link [1](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/cloudmonitoring.googleapis.com/overview) in the API manager.

2- The user you are using to connect to the Cloud Console does not have the proper rights on this project.
Your user must have at least the monitoring.viewer role to see the Stackdriver monitoring console and API.
 If the user is the Project owner the monitoring access should be granted as included in the role.
Still, you can check the Stackdriver monitoring Access control guide at these links [2](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/access-control) and [3](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/accounts/guide).

3- The monitoring agent is not installed on the instance.
You can check the quickstart page on how to configure an instance to use Stackdriver monitoring at this link [4](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent).

I hope this helps.

Comment: I checked all three suggestions, with no result. I have identical 8 projects which on all of them I am the owner and the first project through google cloud platform on compute engine tab under each vm instance I get the not enough permissions message which is very weird since as owner I should have full access. I am not checking through any API or something.

Comment: If I understood well you only see the problem on one project of all 8 projects and it is the first project that was created.
In this initial project, do you have this error message for every GCE instance or for only one instance ?
Did you create this project a long time ago ? Maybe Stackdriver monitoring was not available at the time the initial project was created so that could explain that the project owner would not have the credentials to access the monitoring API.
Can you try to add the monitoring.viewer role to your user in IAM and see if you can see the monitoring data ?

Comment: Nop. Didn't work either. Tried that personally when I started troubleshooting. Thanks for all the assistance so far.

Comment: Do you have this error message for every GCE instance or for only one instance ?

Comment: This happens for all instances in the project I am referring to. That's why I believe is a project wide issue. I am the owner of the project so I am confused why this happens as I should have access to everything inside the project.

Comment: Ok, so this does not seem to be an issue with Stackdriver access rights then.Please, try using an incognito window and make sure that you have no adblocker softwared enabled on your browser.

Comment: tried that as well. I also made another user as owner and neither can he see the monitoring tab under vm instance details. So I am thinking to create another project and start transferring the instances in there.

Comment: You might have altered the service account used by the instances of your project. Could you check that the service account used by the instance is valid and still existing in IAM ?

Comment: Yes the service account used by all the instances in the project is still valid in the IAM with the editor permissions on the project.

Comment: I suggest that you open a Public issue tracker from this [link] briefly explaining the issue and to provide your project ID so I could check inside your project.
If you do so, please provide the link to the created issue tracker so I can check it.
[link]: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/112385928 is the link. There was some progress after I posted it but it's been a while since the last update. Also the message changed now to :

Sorry, there’s a problem. If you entered information, check it and try again. Otherwise, the problem might clear up on its own, so check back later.

Comment: Everything is fixed after Gcloud Support investigation. There is a small bug on escaping a keyword of the project name with this causing the error that I was facing.